# Native iOS and Android App Running Remote Web App Inside a WebView

Tags: android, ios, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

I am about to start a project to develop app that will run on iOS and Android. Most of the functionalities are very basic. Creating membership, login, viewing some content, entering forms data etc. However, there will be many pages. It is like a Web Site. iOS and Android App will have same functionalities.

I am considering developing this as Web App then creating a native iOS and Android App with a WebView. In that case, my users will download the apps from App Store and Play Store but my Web App will work inside that native apps.

I am willing to do that because apps functionalities will be same and there many simple pages in the apps. This will give me huge benefits. For example, i will implement once and use it in two different app, create new releases mostly without publishing the apps again etc.

I am planning to implement mobile app related things on the native apps like Push Notifications, Crash Reporting, Google Analytics etc. and rest of the functionalities in the Web App

- Is this a common practice?
- Is there any name for it? (I believe this is not a Hybrid App since Web App will be remote on the cloud)
- What are the possible technical difficulties?
- What other technologies i need?
- How can i done Authentication / Authorization securely (My users will login to app once and then use it without login each use of the app)
- Is there any rule against it? Like does the Apple App Guideline allow it?
- Is there any framework to use for such need?

Thanks

Comment: use something other than just sticking a web view in there. if you want to code once and deploy everywhere, look into, at the very least, react native or xamarin. as for answering those questions, you wont really get that here, thats not what stack overflow is for.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend you to build a native app just for the use of a wrapper. In this case it is better to write a responsive web app. You can bookmark the website on your home screen and it will use the favicon as the apps icon.

Check out **progressive web apps**. This may be what you are looking for:
[Progressive Web Apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_Web_Apps)

Comment: May i ask why you wouldn't recommend? I am willing to use some native abilities that i can use in this native app wrapper. Also letting my users to download my app is something they want.

Comment: Apple for instance does not like that: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/web-views/. The WebView is not for using a web browser in your app, this is safaris job. It is for displaying rich content at some place. So your app may be rejected by the review team. A native app is mainly for native use and its way faster than loading a web page in a web view

Comment: How can you get your progressive web app in the playstore or apple store?